# Reduce allocation sorting large list (or vector)

Tags: sorting, haskell, allocation

I am trying to reduce GC time in my program. The main suspect is the following piece of code:

```
Data.Vector.Unboxed.fromList . take n . List.sortBy (flip $ Ord.comparing id) 
 $ [ ( sum [ (c + a) * wsum z | (z,c) <- IntMap.toList zt_d ] , d)
   | d <- IntMap.keys $ m
   , let zt_d = IntMap.findWithDefault IntMap.empty d $ m ]
```

The list being sorted would typically contain several thousand elements. I think the list sort is the culprit, because if I replace `take n . List.sortBy (flip $ Ord.comparing id)` with `return . List.maximum` my productivity goes from 60% to 95%.

Is there anything I can do to reduce allocation here?

**Update**

As recommended, I replaced the List.sort by an inplace sort from `vector-algorithms`.
Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but what I'm seeing is that there is no allocation (productivity 97% as opposed to 63% with lists), but the program is many times slower: it runs in 85 seconds with List.sortBy; with inplace sort I killed it after 
waiting 7 minutes. I tried both Intro and Merge sorts. Here is my code:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as GM
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Merge as Sort
import qualified Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream as Stream
import Control.Monad.ST   

sortBy :: (Ord a, U.Unbox a) => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> U.Vector a
sortBy cmp xs = runST $ do
  mv  <- GM.unstream . Stream.fromList $ xs
  Sort.sortBy cmp mv
  G.unsafeFreeze mv
```

Comment: Why `flip $ Ord.comparing id` and not `flip compare`?

Comment: Why don't you put it in a vector first and sort the vector using the `vector-algoirthms` package?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: vector-algoirthms sorting functions only work on mutable vectors, no?

Comment: Yes, they require mutable vectors. So you'd fill a mutable vector with the list, sort it and then freeze to obtain an immutable vector. Not as elegant as `fromList . take n . sortBy foo`, but if it's more efficient, it's a good trade-off.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Which of the sorting algorithms in `vector-algorithms` is a good default to use? There seem to be tens of them...

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd start with Introsort, but Merge and Heap are also good candidates. Just try which does best, once you have the code written, it's only a change of import to switch between these.

Comment: Not sure I see the point in all that streaming and unstreaming business. Try something simple like `U.modify (Sort.sortBy cmp) (U.fromList xs)`.

Comment: Also, make sure you're compiling with `-O2` when writing code using the `vector` package. Its performance relies a lot on some optimizations.

Comment: @hammar: Yep, I pretty much always use -O2.

Comment: @hammar: Just tried your suggestion. It's still glacial.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Ah hang on. The original code wasn't sorting the whole list, only a prefix (due to laziness since you were using `take` on the result), so you probably want `partialSortBy` instead of `sortBy`. Also, have you verified that it terminates at all with some small input? You might have accidentally created an endless loop somewhere.

Comment: The above sorting code can sort a list of ~3 million `Int`s according to a somewhat convoluted comparison function in a couple of seconds (surprisingly, heap and intro sort are much slower than merge for that). If your list contains only several thousand elements, you have some deeper problem, I'd think. Can we see more code?

Comment: @hammar: With `Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro.partialSortBy` it now runs in 153 seconds (as opposed to 86 with List.sortBy).
Unfortunately Merge does not have `partialSortBy`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The times I'm quoting are for a program which calls this sort function several thousand times.
At any rate, the complete code is at: https://bitbucket.org/gchrupala/colada/src/ecb116410e18/colada/Colada/WordClass.hs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting does indeed look like it will cause a lot of allocation. While the sorting is performed on a list, that cannot be completely changed, since sorting lists causes the construction of many intermediate lists. If necessary, you could try to do the sorting on an `MVector` using for example the [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) package which provides efficient sorting algorithms.

However, there are further inefficiencies that cause more allocation than necessary in

```
Data.Vector.Unboxed.fromList . take n . List.sortBy (flip $ Ord.comparing id) 
 $ [ ( sum [ (c + a) * wsum z | (z,c) <- IntMap.toList zt_d ] , d)
   | d <- IntMap.keys $ m
   , let zt_d = IntMap.findWithDefault IntMap.empty d $ m ]
```

When you write

```
d <- IntMap.keys m, let zt_d = IntMap.findWithDefault IntMap.empty d m
-- The '$' are unnecessary, I left them out
```

you are 1) traversing the entire map to collect the list of keys, and 2) then look up each key on its own. Since you only look up keys present in the map, you never use the default. Much more efficient is to create the list of key/value pairs in one traversal of the map:

```
(d,zt_d) <- IntMap.assocs m
```

Then if `id` in `flip $ Ord.comparing id` is indeed the identity function, that would be more readable (and possibly more efficient) as `sortBy (flip compare)`.

Depending on the type of the summed elements (and possibly the optimisation level), it might be better to use `Data.List.foldl' (+) 0` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Funny I didn't see the silly lookups in IntMap :(. Fixing it gave a small speedup. 
I'll try if using the inplace sort on MVector helps.